# CSS background color not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, jquery-animate, background-color

I don't understand why the background color is not being applied as expected here. This might be a lack of understanding on my part as to the relationships between elements in CSS?

The page in question: http://www.preview.imageworkshop.com/portfolio/

**Replicating the issue**

1. First, open the above link in **IE 7** or **IE 8**
2. Click the PRODUCT filter, then press the PROMO & EDITORIAL filter
3. White dots will have appeared on some of the images (this is a bug in IE which causes some pixels to be left transparent after a fade animation. if you don't see them, do a little more filtering, they turn up fairly quickly.

**CSS BACKGROUND COLOR PROBLEM**

**What works:**
If I set the background color for the gallery background to be red, then this red color shows throught the transparent spots on the images. (The inference here, is that a background color of black hides the 'white spots' bug).

```
#isotopegallery{background:red;}
```

**What doesn't work:**
Obviously, I don't want to set the gallery background color to be anything but white.
What I want to do is set the background color of the DIV that contains the images, for example:

```
.photo{background:red;}
```

however, when i do this, the red background color does not show up through the transparent pixels??

The simplified overview of the structure of the elements is as follows

```
<div id="isotopegallery" class="photos">
    <div id="ngg-gallery-18-71">
        <div class="photo"> <p><a>  <img />  </a></p>   </div>
        <div class="photo"> <p><a>  <img />  </a></p>   </div>
        <div class="photo"> <p><a>  <img />  </a></p>   </div>
        <div class="photo"> <p><a>  <img />  </a></p>   </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**HELP!**

I can't figure out why this background color works for the **#isotopegallery** parent DIV, but not for the **.photo** DIV?

When i look in firebug, the color property is set for the .photo div, but does not show through the transparent pixels?

This is the last issue that his holding up go live for our website, and it is driving me nuts!
I would really appreciate any help that you can provide to help me resolve this issue.

**NOTE:** there is info around that suggests that changing the blackpoint of the images in photoshop will fix this problem. We have tried this method, and have found it does not work.

Comment: You could try setting the 'transparent' background in css.

Comment: firian, thanks for your suggestion, but I don't understand what you are suggesting? The image has transparent pixels which will show through the background color of #isotopegallery, but not that of .photo - I tried setting the .photo img{background:transparent;} but this did not help either (if that was what you were suggesting)

Comment: Actually that's not exactly what I meant. Try setting the "background:transparent;" to image's container. There's small chance that it will fix IE's rendering bug, so it's worth a shot. I can't think of anything else that could help you, so good luck!

Comment: @firian, thanks for the suggestion. Had a go at a few variations on this theme - but none were successful :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this issue. I have posted full details against this thread (link below), which describes the issue in more detail.

[IE fade causing white spots on images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299329/ie-fade-causing-white-spots-on-images/7494510#7494510)

Answer (score 0):

Are you floating the interior elements of `.photo` without clearing them? That would prevent the background color from covering the height of the element in question.

If that's the case, appending something like `<br style='clear: both;' />` to the `.photo` div should do the trick.

Likewise, you could always try applying the background color to the `img` elements themselves: `.photo img { background-color: red;}`

Comment: Don't think that this is the problem. if I remove the images, I see blocks of colour. 
I have also tried applying the background colour directly to the img as you have suggested and that does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

The creator of isotope has been helping me look at this issue, and has added the following comment:

> "Did some more testing. I've come to the conclusion IE treats the
>   entire element, which contains the image, as one 'image'. Whatever is
>   visible gets flattened. If that element has a true-black pixel within
>   an image, than that pixel *of the element* will be treated as
>   transparent, regardless of what's actually behind the image.
>
> Take a look at: http://support.metafizzy.co/2011/09-06-ie-trans.html
>
> You'll see a couple transparent pixels pop up, even though the
>   background of each item is clearly red (items have padding, background
>   is red). I then dynamically changed their color to blue and the pixel
>   is still transparent.
>
> Which means the only pure-CSS solution is to set the container
>   background to black"

Not sure where to go from here. We have tried moving the black point (as this is supposed to be caused by true black pixels), but have found this to be an unsucessful method.

Comment: Redirect visitors with IE to a page where they can download chrome or firefox?